# How to Get Data size of Cosmos DB from a Subscription using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I want to get Data sizes of **Cosmos DB Storage Accounts** from multiple Subscriptions.
For instance, we have a Subscription which has 4 Cosmos DB Accounts in 4 regions.

```html
PS V:\> Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts | ft

Name       ResourceGroupName ResourceType                          Location   
----       ----------------- ------------                          --------   
Account1   dbcosmosdb      Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts eastasia   
Account2   dbcosmosdb      Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts eastus2    
Account3   dbcosmosdb      Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts northeurope
Account4   dbcosmosdb      Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts westus
```

Now I would like to query all 4 Cosmos DB Accounts to get the Data size used of each Account.

Example, **Account1** has **137 GB** Used so far. I would like to see that Number using **Powershell** so that i can query through multiple Subscriptions and add this my telemetry reporting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`Get-AzMetric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azmetric?view=azps-2.7.0) command, try the script as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$ids = (Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts).ResourceId
foreach($item in $ids){
    $name = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $item).Name
    $metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId $item -MetricName "DataUsage" -WarningAction Ignore
    $data = ($metric.Data | Select-Object -Last 1).Total/1024/1024/1024
    Write-Output "$name : $data GB"
}
```

Comment: Hello @Joy Wang,
Really sorry for late response. I fell under the weather past one week. Just came back to office today. 

Yes. Your small for loop which is going through each Storage Account is awesome. It is solving my Storage usage problem for COSMOS DB type.

Comment: Hello @Joy Wang. Your answer helped me find the Cosmos DB Usage. But I'm not finding the button for Mark as Answer.